# Does the same attribute modifier necessarily count as the same source when adjudicating stacking rules?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ability-scores, stacking

the SRD says this about stacking:

> Stacking
>
> In most cases, modifiers to a given check or roll stack (combine for a cumulative effect) if they come from different sources and have different types (or no type at all), but do not stack if they have the same type **or come from the same source (such as the same spell cast twice in succession).** If the modifiers to a particular roll do not stack, only the best bonus and worst penalty applies. Dodge bonuses and circumstance bonuses however, do stack with one another unless otherwise specified.

(emphasis mine).

**Does the same attribute modifier necessarily count as the same source?**

Case A: for example, would the Wisdom modifier melee bonus damage from the epic prestige class Perfected One (Epic Level Handbook) stack with the Wisdom modifier bonus damage of the Shiba Protector prestige class (Oriental Adventures)?

Case B: would the bonus type make a difference? As an abstract example, would adding the Charisma modifier as a *sacred* bonus to reflex saving throws from class feature A and a the Charisma modifier as an *insight* bonus to reflex saving throws from class feature B stack?

Case C: would the kind of enabler matter? For example, if we had the Gauntlets of Heartfelt Blows (adds the Charisma modifier as bonus fire damage to melee attacks) and an imaginary class feature that adds the Charisma modifier to damage - would they stack?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. Out of curiosity, was this brought to your *3.5* table by a *Pathfinder* player? If you've arrived at this question independently, good show and carry on. Thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: Thank you! No, it was a 3.5 player :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type and Source of the modifier is what determines if they stack.

From the [SRD on the Basics](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm):

> **Stacking**
>
> In most cases, modifiers to a given check or roll stack (combine for a
> cumulative effect) if they come from different sources and have
> different types (or no type at all), but **do not stack if they have the
> same type or come from the same source** (such as the same spell cast
> twice in succession). If the modifiers to a particular roll do not
> stack, only the best bonus and worst penalty applies. Dodge bonuses
> and circumstance bonuses however, do stack with one another unless
> otherwise specified.

Emphasis added by me.

So in summary:

- A: If the type is the same and not "circumstance" or "untyped", then no. Otherwise, yes.
- B: Yes, the bonus type matters.
- C: It depends on the type of bonus each source gives. See point A.

Comment: Thank you!
Does "untyped" count as a type in this context? Usually, untyped bonuses stack. So would two distinct, untyped bonuses based on the same attribute modifier stack?
(Should I edit this Case D to the original question?)

Comment: @Haraldhinio Ideally your question should raise all points that need answers to "solve" your problem, so you may update it with a Case D if you feel it helps. "Untyped" behave like "Circumstance", in that they stack with other "Untyped". The "Same Source doesn't stack" rule still applies, so no double Haste. From there it would be up to the DM. A good example of a core "Untyped" bonus is the +1 to attack you get from [Haste](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/haste.htm).